# llvm: file format not recognized; treating as linker script

Tags: c, gcc, google-cloud-platform, llvm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross compile the Google Cloud Platform IoT SDK but I'm running into:

`file format not recognized; treating as linker script`.

The compiler command is auto generated but I can't see what's wrong with it.

```
x86-cc   -DIOTC_TLS_LIB_MBEDTLS -DMBEDTLS_PLATFORM_MEMORY -DIOTC_DEBUG_OUTPUT=0 -DIOTC_DEBUG_ASSERT=0 -DIOTC_DEBUG_EXTRA_INFO=0 -DIOTC_FS_POSIX -DIOTC_MEMORY_LIMITER_APPLICATION_MEMORY_LIMIT=524288  -DIOTC_MEMORY_LIMITER_SYSTEM_MEMORY_LIMIT=2024  -DIOTC_MEMORY_LIMITER_ENABLED -DIOTC_PLATFORM_BASE_POSIX -DIOTC_MULTI_LEVEL_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE -DIOTC_LIBCRYPTO_AVAILABLE -Wall -Wno-pointer-arith -Wno-format -fstrict-aliasing -Os -Wall -Wextra -Wno-format  -I. -I./third_party/tls/mbedtls/include/ -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/include/bsp -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/libiotc/platform/iotc_thread  -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/include -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/libiotc  -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/bsp/crypto/mbedtls  -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/libiotc/io/fs/posix  -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/libiotc/debug_extensions/memory_limiter  -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/bsp  -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/bsp/platform/posix  -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/libiotc/io/net  -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/libiotc/memory  -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/libiotc/event_loop  -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/libiotc/time  -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/libiotc/tls/certs  -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/libiotc/tls  -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/bsp/tls/mbedtls  -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/libiotc  -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/libiotc/io  -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/libiotc/io/fs  -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/libiotc/event_dispatcher  -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/libiotc/datastructures  -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/libiotc/mqtt/codec  -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/libiotc/mqtt/logic  -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/libiotc/control_topic  -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/third_party/mqtt-protocol-c -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/libiotc/platform/posix -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/libiotc/platform/posix/iotc_thread -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/third_party/cmocka/include/ -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/tests -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/tests/tools -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/tests/itests -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/tests/itests/tools -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/tests/itests/tools/dummy -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/libiotc -I/home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/tests/itests/platform/posix/iotc_thread -MM /home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/src/bsp/crypto/mbedtls/iotc_bsp_crypto_mbedtls.c -MT /home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/obj/bsp/crypto/mbedtls/iotc_bsp_crypto_mbedtls.o -MF /home/nate/gcp/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/obj/bsp/crypto/mbedtls/iotc_bsp_crypto_mbedtls.d
/home/nate/sdk-qemu/toolkit/compilers/llvm-8.0.0.2/LINUX64/bin/ldpentium:/tmp/iotc_bsp_crypto_mbedtls.o.34065: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/home/nate/sdk-qemu/toolkit/compilers/llvm-8.0.0.2/LINUX64/bin/ldpentium:/tmp/iotc_bsp_crypto_mbedtls.o.34065:1: syntax error
```

Each time I run the make command, the a new iotc_bsp*.o file is generated giving the same error.

Comment: Generally this means you are compiling your source file for one computer architecture and trying to link the object modules using a linker for a different computer architecture.

Comment: Hmmm. Running `file` on the .o file gives `ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped`. But the target is x86. The compiler is also x86 so I'm not sure how that's happening

Comment: Adding the -m32 flag turns them into 32 bit files, but I still have the issue

Comment: There are multiple object file formats: ELF, COFF, OBJ. Linux is typically ELF. What does your linker require for your target platform? Which target CPU?

Comment: Turned out to be a compiler driver issue. It wasn't parsing the -MM and -MF flags correctly. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Post an answer with the solution.